# What type of screws are used to mount an electrical terminal block onto electrical panel box?

Tags: electrical-panel

I need to add a terminal block to an NEMA outdoor electrical panel box -- metal box is flush mounted to stucco wall. The terminal block is UL rated and meets NEC/local residential electrical code, and I have approval from local building department to install it for my application, but they didn't specify what type of screws to use. I can't find a definitive source on what to used. The panel box will be mounted on a stucco wall, so the screw length can't penetrate the stucco. Can I use regular, or self-tapping Sheetmetal screws, or machine screws with nuts -- and drill holes? If the screw is too long, can I cut it off, or break it off etc.? Does it need to be corrosion proof? What is the standard practice for this application? Lots of questions ...

AL

Comment: Can you provide the make and model of terminal block you're using please? The precise specifics of its UL approval *matter* in this case...

Comment: It's a Schneider Electric UL Square D panel box and Square D single terminal block rated @ 175A CU and 135A AL 600V. Maximum current through the block is 70A protected by a 70A circuit breaker (2 pole @ 240V) using AL 2/3 service entrance cable. If you want a specific part number, then feel free to look it up online. Also, all my electrical work is permitted, installed according to 2020 NEC, and local code, and will be inspected and signed off by my city after installation. Hope that helps!

Comment: The only 175A rated single pole block I can find in the Square D catalog is the 9080LBA162101, which is *not* the correct part for your application -- it's a UL *component recognized* (RU mark, aka Rather Useless to us) terminal block.  You need a UL *listed* power distribution block here in order to meet the letter of the Code (as set out in NEC 314.28(E)(1))  -- in the Square D product line, the closest product to what you're wanting to install that has an actual *listing* is the NSYEBAP12611.

Comment: If my AHJ approves UR terminal block, then it's not a problem. As I read it, UR is listed when adding an item to an already listed parted part or component. It's hard to believe Schneider would expose themselves using inferior parts. I will follow up with my AHJ. Thanks for bringing this to my attention!

Comment: Also, the difference between them is higher amps and the terminal block is completely insulated against shock hazard. Nice to have, but absolutely necessary -- it depends?  This is a meter box which doesn't require a lot of rewiring, or changes, and well below max amps intended.

Comment: And protected by a circuit breaker.

Comment: Then again, Schneider just had a recall on some of their panel boards due to bus bar over heating -- UL rated!

Answer (score 2):

In this case the choice of hardware is entirely up to you. The NEC uses phrases like "good and durable quality" and "neat and workman-like manner" when describing things that are left to the discretion of the installer.

When you say the screws "can't" penetrate the stucco, it's not clear whether you mean literally that the screws won't be able to penetrate the stucco, or whether you mean it's undesirable for them to do so.

Ordinary zinc-plated hardware is probably fine, unless there's something you know about your environment that suggests they'll deteriorate too rapidly. You could pick stainless steel instead if you prefer. Cutting screws to length is totally acceptable. If you wanted to insert machine screws from the back side of the enclosure before mounting it, so that the screws work as threaded posts, that's fine too. If it helps to shim the enclosure so that there's a gap between it and the stucco surface, go ahead.

If the screw needs to act as part of a grounding path then there are certain requirements -- if I remember correctly there must be at least 1 and a half turns of threads engaging the metal of the box, which usually means using a 32 thread per inch (or finer, I suppose) machine screw. But if your question concerns only mounting, without any need for ground bonding too, then this wouldn't apply to your case.

Comment: Undesirable to penetrate since its just being mounted to the metal panel box. I just need to secure it correctly, and pass inspection. I have a UV hard plastic mounting board for the box attached on the wall studs, so there's a gap between the stucco and box-- it's a meter box downstream from main panel. I can't use the neutral lugs on meter box since they are bonded together with the ground. I have to isolate the neutral from the neutral/ground bar by using the rated terminal block per my inspector which makes sense that only neutrals and grounds are bonded at the main panel.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the other option for a production meter like this would be to use one of Milbank's [solar sockets](https://www.milbankworks.com/getmedia/95784f76-3782-4386-83d2-1a7dc3088a8f/Flyer-Solar-Sockets.pdf) which have a factory isolated neutral bar

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel With supply chain issues, cost and availability, using another vendor's solution isn't an option. Plus, no major electrical supplier i.e., GE, Semians, Eaton etc. offers a meter box that has the neutral and ground separated. It's an easy $10 fix! Also, I looked at Milbank, but it didn't meet my budget and schedule. And I didn't want to buy a whole new box again. FYI, the fixed (terminal block) was approved by my city's electrical inspection department, so it's legal for me, but may not be in allowed in your jurisdiction, please contact your local authority for approval etc.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning -- what I'm saying (between this and my comment on the question) is that your AHJ is playing fast and loose by approving this part for *any* field installation.  in the SqD lineup, the NSYEBAP12611 is a suitable replacement (although somewhat chunkier).  if that's too expensive/unobtanium for your tastes, then you can use a Mersen MPDB63151 instead -- it carries the correct UL listing, and is actually cheaper than the SqD 9080 terminal block you ordered

Answer (score -1):

Stucco will not hold anything, at best it is 1 inch thick.

You need to reach the plywood panels, behind the stucco and behind the insulation to have solid installation.

Typically those screws need to be  > 3 inch long

Comment: Got that covered ... just have a question on the mounting things inside the panel box.